# Understanding Block Diagram for Load Switch

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, level-shifting, mosfet-driver

I'm looking at the [Vishay SiP32431](http://www.vishay.com/docs/66597/sip32431.pdf) and am confused by the block diagram, copied below.

[image: block diagram]

I understand the P-Channel at the top, but what are the triangles? What is the difference in level-shifting this way compared to an N-channel MOSFET or NPN BJT?

Answer (score 1):

The first triangle is a buffer followed by a level translator which will help in turning ON the P-channel MOSFET with control voltages much lesser than the voltage applied at the IN input pin. For example, you can use a 1.5V logic to turn ON a 5V load.

The second triangle seems to be a [slew rate limiter](http://www.ti.com/tool/tipd140) which will help in linear ramp up of the output voltage so as to maintain inrush current limits in the circuit.

Now, I am not saying that these features cannot be accomplished with a discrete MOSFET circuit. But that will involve adding extra components to the drive circuit of your MOSFET. The SiP32431 device will provide you with a single-chip solution to accomplish all these requirements.